# PDO MySQL query failing with more than one comparison operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm sure I'm just formatting this incorrectly but I'm getting a PDO exception with one of my queries and the debug isn't helping.

if I run the following it's works fine :

```
$db = static::getDB();

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM djs WHERE day = :day 
                 AND start_hour = :hr AND shifts LIKE :shift';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':day', $arr['day'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':hr', $arr['hr'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':shift', $shift, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

But when I try to add more than one comparison operator in the query like this :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM djs WHERE day = :day 
                 AND start_hour > :hr AND end_hour <= :hr 
                 AND shifts LIKE :shift';
```

It throws the following exception pointing to the line containing the execute command :

```
Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'
Message: 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'
```

`end_hour` is a valid column in the table and I'm trying to ascertain if the `star_hour` is greater than `:hr` and the `end_hour` is less than or equal to `:hr`. I must be doing this wrong. Any pointers please? It is because I'm using the same named parameter `:hr` in the query twice but only binding it once? If so what is the solution other than setting up another named parameter with the same data?

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson Thanks that answered my question. Sorry for the repeat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use different names for the parameters, even if you are using the same value:

```
$db = static::getDB();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM djs WHERE day = :day 
                 AND start_hour > :hr1 AND end_hour <= :hr2 
                 AND shifts LIKE :shift';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':day', $arr['day'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':hr1', $arr['hr'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':hr2', $arr['hr'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':shift', $shift, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: So the only option is to repeat yourself like I mentioned in the question? Why doesn't PDO allow for the use of the same named parameter twice in the same query? Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: @spice: read this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php